# Can't run Laravel apt on Ubuntu 22.04 because it uses OpenSSL 3

Tags: server, 22.04, ssl, openssl, laravel

When I visit my Laravel site, I get the error:

```
file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading
```

I've searched and searched and found that OpenSSL 3 is the default for Ubuntu 22.04 and Laravel cannot use OpenSSL 3. Has anybody dealt with this? How do you get it to work?